# passing parameters/arguments to a jenkins groovy script outside of pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

I am trying to create an Active Choice input that will dynamically change its values based on another combo box.  The code is below...when i run this, it the 'select_tag' input is not populated.   I see one warning in the jenkins console output:  `WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'org.biouno.unochoice.model.GroovyScript': parameters`

But nothing else.  Anyone know how to do this properly?
How do we debug these kind of scripts that are run on initialization of the page?  where are the exceptions outputs logged to?

```
def proj_tag_map = ['proj1': ['1.0.0', '1.0.1'], 'proj2': ['2.0.0', '2.0.1'] ]                      
def projects = proj_tag_map.keySet() as ArrayList

build_tag_input(proj_tag_map)

pipeline {
    agent any 
    parameters{
      choice(name: 'project', choices: projects) 
    }
    ...
    ...
}

def build_tag_input(proj_tag_map){
   properties([
      parameters([
         [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            name: 'select_tag',
            referencedParameters: 'project',
            script: [
                  $class: 'GroovyScript',
                  script: [

                     sandbox: true, 
                     script: """
                        return proj_tag_map[project]
                     """.stripIndent()
                  ]
            ]
         ]
      ])
   ])
}
```

**UPDATE:**  i can reference the variable through string interpolation.  So i can do this:

```
tags = "${proj_tag_map[project]}"
return tags.tokenize(",")
```

**But the problem is it seems to work only once on page refresh.**  I can see that when the user changes selection of a project, that value is getting changed and can be seen in the select_tag scripts, but for some reason, my list of tags remains the same - it isnt switching. almost as though it's not indexing into the map the 2nd time or that once the jenkins job page is rendered, those function calls in the script element are now nothing but static strings and not really dynamic any longer - which seems silly if that is the case.  Im really starting to hate Jenkins :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
def list = []
list.add(choice(name: 'project', choices: projects))
properties([parameters(list)])

pipeline {
...
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont understand what you are trying to propose. i can access the project referenced paramter fine. i can not access the declared map 'proj_tag_map'

Comment: what I wanted to stress is that declaring parameters within the pipeline block might not work together with the dynamic generation of the list. so either make it the dynamic way or statically.

Comment: i still dont understand how your proposed code is allowing the list to tag lists to change when the user selects a project from the project drop down.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, i had to implement and ugly hack - that is to embed the map into the script, then deserialize it when the script handler is invoked.  ugly, but works:

```
def embedded_map = "${proj_tag_map.inspect()}"     
def amap = evaluate(embedded_map) 
return amap[project]
```